# How can I append data to a file on google cloud storage

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a CSV file on google cloud storage using google cloud function. Now I want to edit that file - is it possible to append data in that file? If yes, then how?

Comment: See if either of these assist ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487432/how-to-append-files-in-gcs-with-the-same-schema and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715217/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-gcs-bucket-in-append-mode-using-python

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. but it will not work for large files

Comment: Which proposed workaround does not work for large files ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append write to google cloud storage file from app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876780/how-to-append-write-to-google-cloud-storage-file-from-app-engine)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is the Object Storage managed service for Google Cloud Platform. 
Unlike a block storage or file system storage, objects stored are immutable.

As mentioned in [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) :

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
>   change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
>   is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful
>   object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot make
>   incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate
>   operations. However, it is possible to overwrite objects that are
>   stored in Cloud Storage, and doing so happens atomically — until the
>   new upload completes the old version of the object will be served to
>   readers, and after the upload completes the new version of the object
>   will be served to readers. So a single overwrite operation simply
>   marks the end of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of
>   a new immutable object's lifetime.

As a workaround, we can consider to upload multiples files to a bucket, and then [create a new object by composing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) all previous ones.

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

Note that this `compose` command is also available via `JSON API` :

```
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/destinationObject/compose
```

And via [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)

So this call could be easily integrated into your code. Be sure to grant before needed role to access to bucket.

[Check official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose)

Comment: Worth to mention, that there is a limit (25 Apr 2022) for objects to be merged together: "There is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation."

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this python script to append data to a csv files. This script will download the file, append the data and uploadit again to the same file in your bucket. You can implement this easily in your Cloud Function.

```
import csv
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('thehotbucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('data1.csv')
blob.download_to_filename('data1.csv')
fields = ['first', 'second', 'third']
with open(r'data1.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)

blob = bucket.blob("data1.csv")
blob.upload_from_filename("data1.csv")
```

If you only want to merge files you can use the gsutil command

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/obj1
```

Comment: first solution is going to take too much time  if file size is large, can you please tell more about gsutil command

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose) _"The compose command creates a new object whose content is the concatenation of a given sequence of source objects under the same bucket"_. You can run this command in your Cloud Shell specifying the desired documents to append and it will append this documents into a new one

Comment: Note that this compose command is also available via Json Api or via Cloud libraries, see my answer

Comment: @Chris32  blob.download_to_filename('data1.csv') download and open file in 'wb' mode so this is causing error inside my GCP function.

Comment: why are you using the 'wb' mode instead of 'a'?

Comment: And please share the details with us... (error, what are you trying to do, your code if is possible) Also please note that I said "im using this python script", if you want to doenload a blob in your Cloud function you want to download it to tmp file so use the route "/tmp/data1.csv" instead

Answer (score 3):

GCS is an Object Storage  and dont allow to update/edit a file once pushed to a GCS bucket.

The only way to update a file which lives in a GCS bucket is to download the file --> Make required changes and then push back to GCS bucket. This will overwrite the file with new content.