# How to concatenate multiple csv file into one csv file having single header with gsutil

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, data-science, gsutil

I tried to concatenate multiple csv file with gsutil cat and gsutil compose but the problem is that in the output file the header is getting repeated which result in data discrepancy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I append data to a file on google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947608/how-can-i-append-data-to-a-file-on-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: gsutil does not process the data within files or objects. You will need to use a different tool to concatenate CSV formatted files. This is a very simple task for a Python program.

Comment: What about avoiding the header lines all together? If for example using `bq extract ... gs://table-name*.csv.gz` to generate multiple gz files, you can specify the `--noprint_header` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly with gsutil. But I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57) where I use BigQuery to (try to) solve this problem